# Qml: Accessibility not working for all elements

Tags: qt, qml

I am adding accessibility to QML application. While using Windows Narrator or NVDA program, they are not able to read elements of ComboBox. They read ComboBox fine but not content of it.
Cannot post my project to posting example file here.

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
Item {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


    ComboBox{
        model: ["option1","option2","option3"]
        Accessible.name: "ComboBox"
        Accessible.description: "ComboBox"


    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

    view.setSource(url);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Qt Version: 5.15.2, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after browsing QT Bugs found out that QML is not fully supported for accessibility and QT is aware of it since 2016. This ticket is really helpful
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68465 and from comments

> Qt should actually be setting focus to the menu's first child menu item, since this is thew behavior VoiceOver expects. We currently don't do this.

So by forcing focus this can be fixed, i am able to fix it.
Check `focus:true` that is most important part.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
Item {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    

    ComboBox{
        id: selectMe
        model: ["selectMe1","selectMe2","selectMe3"]
        focus: true
        Accessible.role: Accessible.ComboBox

        contentItem:
            Text {
            id: ld2
            text: selectMe.currentText
          
           }

        
        hoverEnabled: true
        popup: Popup {
            y: selectMe.height - layoutRowHeight
            width: selectMe.width
            implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
            padding: 1
            focus: true
       

            contentItem: ListView {

                spacing: 2
                focus: true
                Accessible.role: Accessible.List
                clip: true

                implicitHeight: contentHeight
                model: selectMe.popup.visible ? selectMe.delegateModel : null
       
                delegate: ItemDelegate {
                    id: selectMeDelegate
                    width: selectMe.width
                     focus: true
                    contentItem:
                        Text {
                        text: modelData
                        color: "black"
                        font.pointSize: 12
                        elide: Text.ElideRight
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                        focus: true
                        Accessible.name: "selectMe combobox"
                        Accessible.description: "selectMe"

                    }
                    background: Rectangle{
                        width: selectMe.width
                        height: selectMe.height
                       
                    }
                }

            }

            background: Rectangle {
                color:"grey"
                opacity: 0.5
                radius: 10
            }
        }
    }

}
```